# Include Time In PostDate/DateTime Field Control Panel Display

Tags: datetime, postdate

In Craft 3 if you use a [DateTime field](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/date-time-fields.html) and have it set to time only, it still displays as a date in the Control Panel with no time.

Even if it is used as a date and time field, just like entry post date it will only display time if it's on the current day.

Is there a way to modify this format to include the time in the control panel display?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin for Craft 2 that did this called [BigDates](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/BigDates).

As of 7/19/2018, it's been ported to Craft 3 on the v2 branch, but not tested or added to the Plugin Store yet, so there might still be some issues: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/BigDates/tree/v2